# replacing specific values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large df with values in a column with the sequence pattern: seq(1,3000,10).

I need to change every value in the column so that

```
1 = 1
11 = 2
21 = 3
31 = 4
41 = 5
```

The order of these numbers are jumbled in places, therefore I need to define that every 1 is converted to 1, 11 to 2, 21 to 3, 31 to 4 and so on for thousands of numbers with this sequence pattern.

Comment: By *or thousands of numbers with this sequence pattern* do you mean it continues to `101, 111, 121, ...`? And the corresponding new values will be `11, 12, 13, ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
x <- seq(1, 100, by = 10)
# [1]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
```

You can use `%/%`:

```
x %/% 10 + 1
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```